# My question is about using -1900 in tm_year

Tags: c++, tm, time.h

I'm learning `c++` in university and there is a piece of code that I don't understand one thing about. I use `+1900` but my professor uses `-1900` in the comment line.

```
Fecha& Fecha::operator +=(int days) {
tm f = {};
f.tm_mday = day_ + days;
f.tm_mon = mon_ - 1;
f.tm_year = year_ - 1900; //there is my dude, why out -1900 and not +1900 
                         //instead like below
mktime(&f);
day_ = f.tm_mday;
mon_ = f.tm_mon + 1;
year_ = f.tm_year + 1900;
return *this; 
}
```

Comment: The two codes have a different order of operands

Answer (score 4):

In [`struct tm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/), `tm_year` is the year since 1900. So to convert from a Gregorian year to the right `tm_year` value, you subtract 1900. To convert from `tm_year` to the Gregorian year, you add 1900.

The two operations have to be opposite to each other - one adding and one subtracting - as otherwise if you converted back and forward multiple times, you'd end up changing the value more and more.

Comment: thank you very much, sorry if my english isnt the best or the post is poorly structured, is my first time in this website.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the complete code, so I'm *guessing* that `year_` is a member of your class.

In that case, you have to refer to the range of this value. `struct tm` expects a year to be the number of years since 1900. 
If your class stores the number of years since Jesus Christ birth, then you'll have to remove 1900 to go from your member expectation to `tm`'s expectation.

For example, you'll store `2019` in your `year_` member, yet `tm.tm_year` needs `119` (thus `2019 - 1900`).

Doing the opposite, you'll have to reverse the operation, that is adding 1900.